# How to split lines in SQL table according to rules?

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I have SQL table with many lines. It looks like this (just a couple lines from the top):

[image: Table example]

I need to disperse revenue according to project duration equally every 2 months starting first month. So desired result would look like this:

[image]

What's the baest way to achieve this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Does the desired result really match the given sample data?

Comment: It is sql-server. The main thing is to have the revenue divided according to the duration. It's like forecast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive `cte` :

```
with cte as (
     select code, finish2 as acc_date, dateadd(month, project_duration, finish2) as end_date
     from table t
     union all
     select code, dateadd(month, 2, acc_date), end_date
     from cte c
     where dateadd(month, 2, acc_date) < end_date
)
select code, acc_date
from cte c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table or a query containing the dates ranges for each project. Then you JOIN those 2 tables - which will create as many lines for each project as there are dates ranges and you can divide the total revenue by a count(*) of dates ranges or something similar for each line.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer; if you lack the reputation to comment you should generally aim to avoid posting comments as answers, particularly as it may incur downvoates that diminish reputation